# Application menu options not click able

Tags: unity, gnome, menu

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 and gnome 3.10. Everything was working okay. Suddenly I noticed that application menu options are not clickable for all the applications. I've added a screenshot and the same thing happens for all the applications. I tried resetting unity and removing ~/.config/menu but no luck.

Edit: Everything works fine in Gnome desktop. Options on the upper right corner also works fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

do you mean that when you enable autohide, sometimes, hover the mouse about and it would not reveal? then try changing the sensitivity of bar in unity tweak tool.

if you think that mouse hovers but nothing happens even if you click, then try pressing alt. then the hud comes up. then click something and it would work.

Comment: I didn't meant about the launcher. Its the menu options for example the options under file menu in the screenshot. You can see they are blurry and not clickable.